# DataSync for PhoneGAP/HTML5 apps

Tags: html, cordova

What kind of data sync options are available for HTML5 apps. I have services with lot of data, might need to sync to the HTML5 client. What is used for this?  MoSync, or ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PhoneGap, I have created a Sync Plugin to synchronize the local database with the Cloud. You can get the details here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/whymDe-BHJ4

The current version works with Android. iOS support will come in the next OpenMobster release

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of OpenMobster

Thanks